# How to add a TableView with NavigationBar (Navigation Controller) to a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I got a tabbed application like this:

[image: Screenshot]

and already set up everything like it should look, but it won't function yet. I already googled my problem and they said you first need to set up a NavigationController with the table view as rootView and then the NavigationBar but I really couldn't figure it out. Hope someone of you can help me.

Comment: what is it that you're trying to accomplish? What do you want the app to do? What is the navigation bar for? Do you just want a list->detail view setup?

Comment: i basicly just want the settings like the settings app on ios devices but i have a tabbar aswell and i need to combine that.

Comment: so if i e.g. press on URL there should be view pushed in form the right and the navigation bar should show the title of the view and the "back" arrow/button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment on your question here is what you should be doing:

First off, in order to make it look like the settings app table, you will need to change the style of your `UITableView` to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Your hierarchy will consist of the following:

The viewcontroller that is actually added into your `UITabBarController` viewControllers array(since I see you have a tabbar as your lowest level of navigation) should be an `UINavigationController`. The root viewcontroller of the navigation controller should be the uiviewcontroller subclass you made that contains your table view. (let's say it's called `SettingsViewController`)

`SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];`

`UINavigationController *settingsNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];`

You will probably need to create a different UIViewController subclass for each type of detail pane you're going to want (if they have different functionality).

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` `UITableViewDelegate` function, you will create the appropriate detail viewcontroller and push it onto your navigation stack.

Let's say you have a volume settings view controller as an example. The following is the code you would have in the function I just mentioned. Keep in mind you also need to actually check the index and/or section of the selected row to figure out which detail view should be shown.

`VolumeSettingsViewController *volumeSettings = [[VolumeSettingsViewController alloc] init];`

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:volumeSettings animated:YES];`

By default, this will function pretty much like the Apple Settings app navigation. The navigation bar will automatically have a "back" button to take you back to the settings view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Storyboard, select your view controller, go to the "Edit" menu and choose, "Embed in Navigation Controller."

Answer (score 0):

If not using story boards, assuming this will be done in code, you need to create things in a reverse order of their hierarchy - something like this:

- Create an instance of the Einstellungen tab's TableViewController using initWithNibName:
- Create a UINavigationController using initWithRootViewController: and setting the Einstellungen as the root
- Create a UITabBarController and set your navigation controller as one of the view controllers of this tab bar controller
- Add the tab bar controller as a subview to the main window in your application delegate

This will create this hierarchy:

Tab bar controller
 ->view controller: Navigation Controller -> root view controller: Einstellungen